# jQuery - Modal Does not display

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to append some data to a table in a boostrap modal, which is returned from PHP and displayed using jQuery. But it is not working properly.

When I put an alert, it shows the data returned from PHP, but the data is not appending or displaying modal.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.btn-info', function() {
  var row = $(this).closest("tr"); // Find the row
  var text = row.find(".book_id").text();

  $.ajax({
    async: false,
    url: "../../svr/lib/view-book-details.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: {
      text1: text
    },
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(data) {
      //alert(data);
      $('#view-table').append(data);
      $('#viewModal').modal("show");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="viewModal" class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Add New Publisher</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body modal-heigt">
        <table class="table table-bordered" id="view-table">

        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you show ajax response?

Comment: Until alert on success function, it is working properly,

Comment: check your network tab, probably your file path is incorrect. Add error object and output the error in console

Comment: No,Mr.Alien, Path is ok, i can see data, which returns from php using alert

Comment: change datatype text to json and return your data In json Format.

Comment: Is `data` valid HTML with `<tr>` and `<td>` ?

Comment: yes, There was no error, can you tell me, i have change to async:false,how do i remove?? I think problem should be there.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an hidden button in the html:

```
<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#viewModal" style="display:none;" id="modalHiddenCallBtn"></button>
```

Then you can call the click event on this button:

```
success: function (data) {
  $('#view-table').append(data);
  $('#modalHiddenCallBtn').click();
}
```

Comment: It is display and instantly disappearing

Comment: I have tested the code. It is working properly. Disappearing of the modal may be due to some other reason (check the console for any error). Anyhow can you give me a dummy **data**. So that I can tell you about how to append it in the modal?

Comment: ( It is display and instantly disappearing )  it possible if jquery is 2 or more time declared in html.

Comment: Problem with jquery, i can view modal using button without using jquery

Comment: Ya then it might be due to the ajax call. There is no problem with jquery. To test that, write this line `$('#modalHiddenCallBtn').click();` outside the ajax call. I mean just after `$(document).ready()`

Comment: No problem is same, @NikhilThakur I have used `async:false`, how do i remove it, i know it should not use, but i can't found error

Comment: [https://github.com/nikhilthakur001/modal_show_on_ajax_call] I have made a repo on my git. It has the same code that you have mentioned in the question.
I have added a hidden button and click event in ajax call to toggle Modal and it is working perfectly. There might be some other issue. You will have to check further. ThankYou :)